# JavaScript object with key that has no value

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

In the TypeScript code listing 1.5 in the [Angular 2 - Meteor tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping#rootcomponent), an object is given which has a key (`template`) but no value:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template
})
```

This appears to be a new feature of EC6, since the following executes happily in a browser Console:

```
valuelessKey = 2,{ key: "value", valuelessKey}
> Object {key: "value", valueLessKey: 2}
```

Note: a variable with the name `valuelessKey` must first be given a value, otherwise errors such as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" or "Uncaught ReferenceError: valuelessKey is not defined" may occur.

What is this feature called and where is it officially described?

Comment: Short-hand syntax; it’s indeed a new feature in ES6. Just check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).